# How to use jQuery autocomplete with Node.js

Tags: jquery, rest, service, autocomplete

I am trying to implement the jQuery autocomplete with a Node REST service but can't get it work.

This my source code:

Autocomplete:

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
        source: function (req, res) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.example.com:3000/autocomplete",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    term: req.term 
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    res($.map(data.results, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.id,
                            value: item.id
                        };
                    }));
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.status + ' : ' + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        }    
    });
```

Node service:

```
exports.find = function(req, res) {
var b=req.params.term;
console.log(b);
db.collection('publication', function(err, collection) {
      collection.find({type:'pub',content: new RegExp(b, 'i') }).limit(5).toArray(function(err, items) {
                res.jsonp(items);
            });
        });
};
```

**b** appears undefined in the console and the autocomplete does not work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if someone needs it

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
autocomplete=require('./routes/autocomplete');


var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
 app.use(express.logger('dev')); /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
 app.use(express.bodyParser());
});


app.get('/autocomplete/:search',autocomplete.find);

app.listen(6000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

**autocomplete.js**

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var Server = mongo.Server,
        Db = mongo.Db,
        BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
db = new Db('redsocial', server);

db.open(function(err, db) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Connected to 'mydb' database");
        db.collection('publication', {strict: true}, function(err, collection) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    }
});


exports.find = function(req, res) {
var b=req.params.search;
db.collection('publication', function(err, collection) {
      collection.find({type:'pub',content: new RegExp(b,'i')}).limit(5).toArray(function(err, items) {
                res.jsonp(items);
            });
        });
};
```

**jquery**

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
        source: function(req,res) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.ejemplo.com:3000/autocomplete/"+req.term,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    term: req.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    res($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.text,//text comes from a collection of mongo
                            value: item.text
                        };
                    }));
                },
                error: function(xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.status + ' : ' + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {

        }
    });
```

**Source Code:** [Link](http://sw.solfin.net.co/index.php/programacion/node-js)

Comment: This seems like a lot of extra work for stuff that `autocomplete` does for you already.

Comment: @AlexanderCeballos Hey Alexander, thanks for the code. I would like to use this code in a commercial application. It's relatively basic, but just wanted to ask your permission? there would not be any attribution. just let me know pls, thx. then you can delete this comment if you like

Comment: Ok, there is no problem, but If possible I like to know your app.