# jQuery Autocomplete for JSONP doesn't result properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete script as the [sample](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) for remote JSONP datasource on jQuery UI site. The sample script works properly on my site but my code with my datasoruce

My datasource send me a json data like;

```
[{ "id":112,"name":"Serhat", "phone":"035343534"},{ "id":124,"name":"Mehmet", "phone":"242324244"},{ "id":125,"name":"Cemil", "phone":"0984509485"}]
```

Here is my code;

```
 $("#nameSearch").autocomplete({
          source: function (request, response) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: reqUrl,
                  dataType: "jsonp",
                  data: {
                      term: request.term
                  },
                  success: function (data) {
                      response(data);
                  }
              });
          },
          minLength: 3,
          select: function (event, ui) {
              log(ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
          },
          open: function () {
              $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
          },
          close: function () {
              $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
          }
      })._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
          return $("<li></li>")
              .data("item.name", item)
              .append("<a>" + item.name+ "</a>")
              .appendTo(ul);
      };
```

So how can I render this data for showing autocomplete suggestions?

Comment: may be this is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957390/how-to-use-jquery-autocomplete-with-node-js

Comment: If that is what your datasource is actually sending you then you getting a json response, not a jsonp response!  Are you getting errors in the console?  Jsonp requires that the service supports json-p server-side