# JQuery autocomplete with ajax request as source data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, curl, autocomplete

**What I want to do:**

I want to do a input text field with a jquery autocomplete function which gets the source data from a cross-domain curl request. The result should look similar like this: http://abload.de/img/jquerydblf5.png (So I actually want to show additional infos which I get from the curl Request). The URL to get the source data is `http://www.futhead.com/15/players/search/quick/?term=` and in the end I add those letters which are currently typed in at my input field (for example "Ronaldo").

At the moment I only tried to perform the searchrequest without showing all infosin the dropdown as shown in the screen above. I only want to see which playernames I actually got back by the curl request. Later I will try to add more information for the dropdown. Maybe you guys can help me as well with this as well (I think its called custom renderItem ??).

**This is what I've tried:**

```
<script>
 $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'playerscraper.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: function () { 
                return $("#results").val() 
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // I have no idea what this response and map is good for
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.label,
                        id: item.value,
                    };
                }));
            },
        });
    }
});
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

My playerscraper.php is performing the curl request and actually returns a array (tested with echo):

```
$term = $_GET['term'];
$curlRequest = new CurlRequest(); 
$result = $curlRequest->get('http://www.futhead.com/15/players/search/quick/?term=' . $searchterm);
$players = array();

return json_encode($result);
```

**My problem:**

I have no idea how to do the source part for the autocomplete function this way, that I get the right results from the ajax request with my searchterm from the input field. When I type in something in the input field, nothing happens (the function which defines the source is getting called - tested with an alert).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957390/how-to-use-jquery-autocomplete-with-node-js

Comment: This is what I've found and brought me to this what I've tried. But I wasn't successfully yet :/