# JQuery Autocomplete Not Showing Search Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js

Please , I am using JQuery Autocomplete to perform a search from a list of customers retrieved from the database. It works when I pass an array as the source but when I change the source to be from the results obtained from mysql database query, nothing seems to work. I have gone through several other related issues to find a solution but none seems to be related to mine, Please what i am doing wrong
This is my code

```
     app.get('/SendFriendRequest', function (req, res) {

        dbconnection.query('SELECT CONCAT(FirstName," ",LastName," ",MiddleName) As FullName from Customers where FirstName like "' + req.query.term + '"%', function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                data.push(rows[i]);
            }
            var results=JSON.stringify({results:data})

            res.end(query.callback+"("+results +")");
            console.log("\tResponded with '" + results + "'\n");
        });
    })

And at the client side, I have this for my JQuery Autocomplete
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            // req: request has all the outgoing info (to server)
            // res: response is a callback used by jQueryUI's autocomplete
            source: function (req, res) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:3000/SendFriendRequest/",
                    // JSONP to talk to localhost (where my Node server is)
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        term: req.term // term is the value of search input
                    },
                    // data has all the incoming info (from server)
                    success: function (data) {
                        // there is trickery here for non-jQuery ninjas,
                        //     see below for an explanation
                        res($.map(data.results, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.value,
                                value: item.value
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                    // typical ajax error handler, nothing to see here
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert(xhr.status + " : " + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                });

            }
        })
    });

</script>
    <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957390/how-to-use-jquery-autocomplete-with-node-js

Comment: Try using `res.jsonp({results:data})` instead of `var results=..` and `res.end(..` and see if the response is correct first from your browser